# VSCode. Angular auto import uses sources for libraries

Tags: angular, configuration, visual-studio-code, auto-import

I've installed some extensions to improve VSCode usages in angular project. There are [Auto Import](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=steoates.autoimport), [TypeScript Hero](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rbbit.typescript-hero). Right now it helps me import automatically dependencies for my type script classes. But issue is if I use automatic import via popup menu it adds sources dependencies only. I expect for angular dependencies something like:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
```

but there is:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/directives';
```

And in very end it is not compilable because of incorrect import.
Is anyone knows reason and recipe to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19694). It should be fixed for TypeScript 2.7 which will be included in VS Code 1.20.

You can try the fix out today by using the current [VS Code insiders build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) or by using `typescript@next` [with these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript#_using-newer-typescript-versions)